# Purge a queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ for daily transactions. My consumers are .Net desktop applications deployed in multiple machines. Every day the transactions are pushed to queue within a certain time duration only. Beyond that there needs to be a hard stop on any new transaction. I have managed to stop sending new transaction to the queue. However, the existing transactions in the queue also needs to be flushed so that it is not sent to any consumer.
I tried searching for this but did not get any solution for purging a queue except for two options-

- Delete and re-create the queue every day
- Stop all the consumers of the queue

Both of these approaches can be implemented but it requires significant amount of changes on my systems. I want to know if there is a better approach.

Comment: Have you tried using this feature: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

Comment: Thanks I will check this out.

Comment: You have a feature in `rabbitmqadmin` to purge queues, `rabbitmqadmin purge queue name=queue_name`. Even though this would not sophistically be done in your code base, it would mean that you don't need to delete the queues or stop the consumers.

Comment: @PärEriksson Yeah I checked that. I need to do this in C# somehow.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh aha alright. I would expect a `yourQueue.purge()` exists with the AMQP driver you are using. Would a scheduled task (not sure what exists in the C# ecosystem) to call this function be a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no API to purge the queue. There are some commands which can be used with rabbitmqadmin though. I have figured out something and working on it. I will post it here if that works well.

Comment: As there is not any purge API, you could purge all messages in a given queue by consuming all of thems through a classic consumer? Not the best thing but if you have no other choice...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C# you can purge a Queue like this

```
            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

            factory.HostName = "localhost";
            factory.UserName = "guest";
            factory.Password = "guest";

            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueuePurge(queueName);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 4):

This [blog article](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2016-06-14_how_to_delete_all_messages_in_a_queue.html#policy) describes how to purge a queue in RabbitMQ in different ways.

**rabbitmqadmin:** 
The management plugin ships with a command line tool, rabbitmqadmin, which can perform the same actions as the web-based UI (the RabbitMQ management interface).

The script used to purge all messages in a single queue is:

```
$ rabbitmqadmin purge queue name=name_of_queue
```

**HTTP API:** The Rabbitmq Management plugin provides an HTTP-based API for management and monitoring of your RabbitMQ server.

```
curl -i -XDELETE https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST/api/queues/vhost/QUEUE_NAME/contents
```

**Policy:** 
Add a policy that matches the queue names with an max-lenght rule. A policy can be added by entering the Management Interface and then pressing the admin tab. (Don't forget to delete the policy after it has been applied.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have RabbitMQAdmin so had to do it through code.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using HareDu 2 Broker API with the below code. Docs are here: 
https://github.com/ahives/HareDu2

```
var result = _container.Resolve<IBrokerObjectFactory>()
                .Object<Queue>()
                .Empty(x =>
                {
                    x.Queue("your_queue");
                    x.Targeting(t => t.VirtualHost("your_vhost"));
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

If it must be one of those two approaches and you `need to do this in C# somehow` as you said in the comments, then simply [use the HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html). Search on that page `/api/queues/vhost/name/contents` and that's where you'd call delete method.

Comment: That would delete the queue I guess?

Comment: Yes. I didn't paste the correct path-  `contents` is missing at the end. I'll edit the answer

Comment: mountain traveller aslo gave this info as an answer on my answer

Answer (score 0):

Even more specific, from the [HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html): Http verb DELETE on `/api/queues/vhost/name/contents`

Quote: "Contents of a queue. DELETE to purge. Note you can't GET this."

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion by Andy Skirrow (in comments) I have set the 'expiration' for each message before posting it to the RabbitMQ in the JSON payload.

My code-

```
using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(rmq_user, rmq_pass);
    client.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    response = client.UploadString(messagePath, jsonPayload);
}
```

Here is my payload-

```
{"payload":"{\"PerformAutomation\":{\"AutomationInputDictionary\":{\"Search.Ban\":\"Holidays from=10th Mar 2017;Holidays to=13th Mar 2017;WalmartID=00155628;ticket_number=1226004;TicketType=HOLIDAY REQUEST;RawTicketData=PERN: 00155628\\r\\nHoliday Request -------------------- Holiday from 10th Mar 2017 to 13th Mar 2017\"},\"ProcessName\":\"HRProc\",\"ProfileName\":\"HR\",\"APIVersion\":\"\",\"AppId\":\"\",\"CommandExecutionWindow\":\"\",\"CommandGenerationSource\":\"\",\"Country\":\"\",\"Instance\":\"\",\"PartnerId\":\"\",\"ReferenceCode\":\"\",\"Timestamp\":\"5:07 AM\",\"UserName\":\"svcblpr\",\"VID\":\"\"}}","content_type":"string","content_encoding":"test/json","profile":"HR","expiration":604800000,"app_id":"wm_uc1_load_gen_app","source_message_id":"wm_uc1_load_gen_source","header":null}
```

So with this workaround I don't have to purge the queue as the messages will automatically be deleted based on the expiration (milliseconds value) set in the payload.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to purge Non-Zero valued queues, use this:

sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues| awk '{if($2 > 0) print $1;}'| xargs -t -n1 sudo rabbitmqctl purge_queue

Of course you can customize to do it for all queues.